# I cant get current location in react native

Tags: geolocation, react-native, react-native-maps

i am using react-native apps to include a map but i can't make it work.
The map only shows blue map. the marker can be seen but the map is all blue. The map keeps showing the sea only. The GPS is turned on my Android device. Still the map keeps pointing to (longitude, latitude) = (0,0).

How can i solve this? Here's a snippet of my code.

```
export default class MapsScreen extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      initialPosition:{
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
      },
      markerPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
      }
    }
  }

  watchID: ?number = null

  componentDidMount() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {

          var lat = (position.coords.latitude)
          var long = (position.coords.longitude)
          alert(lat + " "+ long )
          var initialRegion ={
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.05,
          }

          this.setState({ initialRegion: initialRegion })
          this.setState({ markerPosition: initialRegion })
      },

       (error) => {alert('Error getting location')
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000
      }
    )
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
      var lastRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        latitudeDelta: 0.05,
      }   
      this.setState({ initialRegion: lastRegion })
      this.setState({ markerPosition: lastRegion })
    })
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
  }
render(){
    return(
      <MapView
        initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}
        style= {{ height: 250, width: '100%'}}
      >
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate = {this.state.markerPosition}
         >
         </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>

    )
  }
}
```

i'm using
"react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.54.0-rc.3",
"react-native-maps": "^0.20.1",

Please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are setting [`initialRegion`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#props) prop when you get the geo-location. This prop is for the initial render.

> **initialRegion**
>
> The initial region to be displayed by the map. Use this prop instead
>   of region only if you **don't want** to control the viewport of the map
>   besides the initial region.
>
> Changing this prop after the component has mounted will not result in
>   a region change.
>
> This is similar to the `initialValue` prop of a text input.

You need to use [`region`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#props) prop.

> **region**
>
> The region to be displayed by the map.
>
> The region is defined by the center coordinates and the span of
>   coordinates to display.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working now.
But can you tell me how do i map multiple markers on the map?
I can only mark a single marker for now

Comment: @Anita there is a detailed example on [documentation of react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/README.md#rendering-a-list-of-markers-on-a-map).